# What kind of curves can be defined in euclidean geometry?

Tags: logic, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

Using the language of Euclidean geometry one can talk about certain curves like the curves that had been studied before the invention of the Cartesian system. By talking about curves I mean I am not certain that for example a spiral had been precisely defined using only the language of euclidean geometry, rather they had been described by using terms like movement, time, velocity, etc.

Now my question is whether the graph of elementary functions can be defined as some loci using only the language of Euclidean geometry in any modern re-axiomatization of euclidean geometry like for example Hilbert's.

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless you say precisely what you mean by "the language of Euclidean geometry".  Are you talking about first-order definability in (say) Hilbert's axioms?

Comment: @EricWofsey yes, but not necessarily first order.

Comment: Analytic geometry (a Cartesian plane over a field) is definable in both the languages of Hilbert's or Tarski's euclidean geometries. If you assume a strong enough continuity axiom you get a cartesian plane over the reals. So I think in principle the elementary functions can be defined using modern axiomatization of geometry.

Comment: What do you mean by "definable" if you aren't restricting to first-order definitions?

Comment: @EricWofsey ok help me to understand what you mean. What I mean is like the way real numbers are defined, they are not first order definable. right?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about "definable" unless you have some very specific language that you are restricting your "definitions" to.  In ordinary mathematics, definitions are within the language of whatever foundation of mathematics you are using (usually, a first-order language of set theory).  But here you want to talk about some more restricted notion of "definition", so you need to say what more restricted language you want to use.

Comment: @EricWofsey Are all definitions in "ordinary mathematics" first order?

Comment: They are first-order *in the metatheory* (i.e., set theory).  The most common way to talk about some restricted kind of definition is to restrict to first-order definitions in some first-order language that is specific to a particular object you are studying, rather than the set theory you use to study all of mathematics.